# Emoji retrieve from mysql database

Tags: php, jquery

[image]

I want to retrieve emoji from mysql db, it is stored as `&amp;#x1f601` in mysql. When I am trying to retrieve it is printing as &#x1f601 directly from # symbol, i.e #x1f601 is printing as a link. How can I display smiley in place of `&x1f601`

`echo $_POST['value']` is the code I am using to retrieve it

Comment: Please show the code you are using to fetch and display the value.

Comment: Please don't forget to show the code that you are using to do this. this will help to find the issue.